# How to avoid a overdetermined system in Modelica?

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica

I am currently creating a pipe based on *Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe* in OpenModelica. The model I am creating is quite similar, but I'm trying to implement the method of characteristics instead.

When I check the model it counts 38 equations and 10 variables, and the system is therefore overdetermined. As far as I know I need every equation that I have coded, and I therefore think that variables and constants are declared wrong.

This is how I generally declare variables and constants:

1. When defining things I want the user to change (in the GUI in OpenModelica) I use `parameter`, e.g `parameter SIunits.Length length=1;`.
2. When defining things I don't want the user to change I use `final parameter`, e.g `final parameter SIunits.Area crossArea=Modelica.Constants.pi*diameter*diameter/4;`.
3. When declaring things I need to use in `equation` I only use the correct type, e.g `Real f "Darcy-Weisbach friction factor";`. I typically have seperate functions which are stored in these variables later in `equation`.
4. When declaring arrays which are used in `equation` I use `final parameter`, e.g `final parameter Real f_array[j_length,i_length];`
5. In `equation`, when storing variables in arrays I do this: `f_array[j,i] = Functions.Friction(v=v,D=diameter,rho=rho, mu=mu, eps=roughness);`.

Below is a simplified snippet of my code. I've left out a number of declarations in order to make it easier to read.

```
    model pipe_MSL
       outer Modelica.Fluid.System system;
       extends Modelica.Fluid.Interfaces.PartialTwoPort;

       // Geometry
       parameter SI.Length length=1 "Length";
       final parameter SI.Area crossArea=Modelica.Constants.pi*diameter*diameter/4;

       // Initialization
       final parameter Medium.AbsolutePressure p_a_start=system.p_start;

       // Method of Characteristics declarations
       Real f "Darcy-Weisbach friction factor";
       Real B "Impedance from MOC";
       Real R "Resistance from MOC";
       final parameter Real dx = length/3
       final parameter Integer N = integer(length/dx)
       final parameter Real dt = dx/a "Time step";
       Real v "Water velocity";

       // Local array storage declarations.
       final parameter Real B_array[T,N];
    
    initial equation
       //Initial condition
       B_array[1,:] = {Functions.B_Impedance(a=a, A=crossArea, g=system.g)*k for k in 1:N};

    equation
       for j in 1:T loop
          //Left boundary condition
          Cm_array[j+1,1] = OpenWPL.Functions.C_minus(Hb=H_array[j,2], B=Bm_array[j,1], Qb=Q_array[j,2]);

          for i in 1:(N-1) loop
             B_array[j,i] = Functions.B_Impedance(a=a, A=crossArea, g=system.g) + R_array[j,i]*abs(Q_array[j,i-1]);;
          end for; 
       end for;
    end pipe_MSL;
```

My questions are:

1. Am I using `parameter / final parameter / Real` and other declarations correctly? I've read the guide from Michael Tiller on variables over and over, but I cannot figure out if I use them correctly.
2. Any specific tips on how to make the system not overdetermined?
3. When simulating (even though the system is overdetermined) I get the error `Internal error Cm_array[2,1] = OpenWPL.Functions.C_minus(H_array[1,2], Bm_array[1,1], Q_array[1,2]) has size size 1 but 0 variables ()`. Any idea how to solve this?

I can post the full version of my code if it is needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: seems to me that you are mixing variables with parameters. Parameters are constrant throughout a whole simulation. So arrays should be declared as variables, i.e. remove final parameter

Comment: The last error is because parameters only have initial equations and should not be solved for in regular equations. Final is used for things that don't change - variables, parameters, or constants. I recommend using constants for array dimensions. Users can also change variables and constants in the GUI and if you give them a Dialog annotation you can control where they show up.

Comment: @AtiyahElsheikh Thank you. Removing final parameter when declaring arrays solved a bunch of my problems. However, when I try to remove `final parameter` from `final parameter Real dx = length/3`(which is constant throughout the whole simulation) I get the error `Dimensions must be parameter or constant expression (in N).` in `Real fp_array[T,N];`. Do you know how to counter this?

Comment: @sjoelund.se After removing `final parameter` the last error disappeared, as you mentioned. I have also declared another boundary condition (which I left out in my original post) which is `H_array[j+1,1]=1;` under `//Left boundary condition` in `equation`. The same error (`Internal error pipe.H_array[3,1] = 1.0 has size size 1 but 0 variables ()`) now appears here. Do you know how to solve this as well? Thank you for your reply!

Comment: @Jonas d_x is a parameter, so you can declare it as a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using parameter correctly and there is one more error:

- You can have initial equations for parameters with `fixed=false`, but it doesn't  seem like `B_array` is a parameter since there's a normal equation for it. So remove parameter in front of `B_array`.
- And the initial equation for `B_array` will not work (see below); erase it to get started
- Alternatively you have to write `B_array(each fixed=false)` and ensure that there initial equations for all elements of `B_array` not just one row.
- You have variables that aren't used (at the moment) - just remove their declarations: `f, B, R, v` (unless there are equations that you haven't given).

Initial equations are only intended to fix states (and sometimes parameters); and the idea is that variables must satisfy the normal equations and the initial equations. Thus having an initial equation that looks like the normal equation doesn't work.

Added: **If** the goal is to write your own time-discretized system of equations that doesn't use Modelica for differential equations I see two possibilities:

- Turn it into a traditional algorithm in a function so that you have `parameter Real B_array[T,N]=myDiscretization(...);` and everything inside the function myDiscretization
- Or just have everything as equations; `Real B_array[T,N]` in the main model.

A tool should be able to see that the equations are parametric and only solve them once.

In both cases you have to be really careful about indices:

- Above it is `i in 1:(N-1)` but using `Q_array[j,i-1]`.
- The initial conditions are for `B_array[1,:]`, but there are normal equations for `B_array[1,:]` as well

So should the initial  equations be for `B_array[:,1]` and the loop for `i in 2:N` instead, since that ensures that all elements have an equation? Or is it subtler?

Comment: I have now removed `parameter` in front of `B_array`, and erased the section below `initial equation`. Next, I moved my initial conditions to under `equation` before my first loop. Also, declarations for `f, B, R, v` are used for equations I haven't given, which all are calculated in separate arrays just like B. 
What do you mean by "...and ensure that there initial equations for all elements of B_array not just one row.". Are my initial conditions not applied for all elements in the first row? Essentially I want B to be calculated for all dx from 1:N in my first time step (T=1). Thank you!

Comment: I might totally have misunderstood the intentions of the code. I assume that B_array was a time-varying matrix, but do you mean that B_array[1,:] is the value at first time step and B_array[2,:] the value at the second time step etc?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. B_array[j,i] is an array where j is the time loop iterator and i is the space loop iterator. So when I try to set B_array[1,:] equal to some value, I tried to set the initial conditions for all i's at time step j=1 (or T=0). Similar, when I try to set B_array[:,1] equal to some value, I try to set the left boundary condition for all j's at i=1 (and B_array[:,N] for the right boundary condition for all j's at i=N).